# Can I use std::minmax_element in a member initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a class that contains a `const std::vector` and stores its min and max:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class MyClass {

public:
    const std::vector<int> v;
    const std::pair<int, int> minmax_v;

    MyClass(const std::vector<int> & v_init)
    : v(v_init),
    minmax_v(*(std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end())), *(std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end()))) {}

};
```

It is possible to somehow use `std::minmax_element` to initialize `minmax_v`? The idea is is to improve performance.

Of course, one could use `std::minmax_element` in the constructor body and drop the `const` for `minmax_v` but that doesn’t feel right either.

Comment: what happens when you try? Please include the error message in the question

Comment: There should be no problem, go for it :) but remember about initialization order of members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a delegating constructor to obtain the pair of `minmax_element()` results in a single argument:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    const std::vector<int> v;
    const std::pair<int, int> minmax_v;

    MyClass(const std::vector<int> & v_init)
    : MyClass(v_init, std::minmax_element(v_init.begin(), v_init.end()))
    {}

private:
    MyClass(const std::vector<int> & v_init,
            std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator,
                      std::vector<int>::const_iterator> p)
        : v(v_init), minmax_v(*p.first, *p.second)
    {}

};
```

Comment: Thanks! Neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking this to improve performance, I want to point out that it may be faster to use a custom loop in this case. In your example, there are two operations which both iterate over the vector: the initialization of `v` and `std::minmax_element` both traverse the input vector. Iterating twice seems not optimal, so it may be better to merge the operations into one loop.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    MyClass(std::tuple<int, int, std::vector<int>>&& x): v( std::get<2>(x) ), minmax_v( std::get<0>(x), std::get<1>(x)) {

}

    static std::tuple<int, int, std::vector<int>> init(std::vector<int> const& v_init) {
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.reserve(v_init.size());
        int min = v_init.front();
        int max = v_init.front();
        for(auto const& x: v_init) {
            v.push_back(x);

            if (min > x) {
                min = x;
            }

            if (max < x) {
                max = x;
            }
        }

        return std::make_tuple(min,max, std::move(v));
    }

public:
    const std::vector<int> v;
    const std::pair<int, int> minmax_v;

    MyClass(const std::vector<int> & v_init): MyClass(init(v_init)) {}
};
```

I am assuming that the input vector is not empty as the original example also dereferences the result `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` without checking it against `v_init.end()`. Since `const` members cannot be initialized in the constructor's body I had to come up with a work-around using a helper tuple.

I also want to say that I would probably prefer using STL algorithms instead of the hand-written loop until I can see a performance issue. [Modern compilers probably merge the two loop into a single loop and produce efficient code.](https://godbolt.org/g/1cD2ou)

Comment: Have you measured that this performs (significantly) better, or are you just assuming?

Comment: @Caleth I didn't measure, I rationalized based on the number of operations in the source. A smart compiler could probably merge the two loops into one and produce identical code. But since the OP said he is concerned with performance I wanted to point this potential optimization.

Comment: Your single loop is still `O(2*n)` (which is `O(n)` Btw)
`std::minmax_element` has lower complexity (*At most `max(floor(3/2(N−1)), 0)` applications of the predicate*)

Comment: @Jarod42 I changed the code to at least compile. I've also modified the answer to not talk about complexity in terms of big-O notation since you are of course right that 2*O(n) = O(2*n) = O(n). The complexity of `std::minmax_element` is also O(n) if I am not mistaken, but it is of course more efficent. But I still think that merging the loop is a meaningful optimization if it matters. Not that I think that it does matter most of the time, especially in constructor code. I've also added a link to a godbolt page with the code where you can see that the loops are actually merged.

Comment: Removing the `const` from OP's members so that you can mutate them in the constructor is pretty bad. Leaving them `public` is unforgivable.

Comment: @Jarod42 minmax is the traditional example used to show the impact of branch prediction: the 3n/2 operations often take longer than the 2n of the more naive version...